# pyschools square root approximation

Tags: python

I am new to Python and stackoverflow. I have been trying to solve Pyschools 'while loop' example for square root approximation (Topic 5: Question 9). However I am unable to get the desired output. I am not sure if this issue is related to the loop or the formula. Here is the question:

> Create a function that takes in a positive number and return 2
>   integers such that the number is between the squares of the 2
>   integers. It returns the same integer twice if the number is a square
>   of an integer.
>
> ---

Examples:

```
sqApprox(2)
(1, 2)
sqApprox(4)
(2, 2)
sqApprox(5.1)
(2, 3)
```

Here is my code:

---

```
def sqApprox(num):
    i = 0
    minsq = 1                           # set lower bound
    maxsq = minsq                       # set upper bound
    while i*i<=num:                     # set 'while' termination condition
        if i*i<=num and i >=minsq:  # complete inequality condition  
            minsq = i
        if i*i<=num and i <=maxsq:  # complete inequality condition
            maxsq = i
        i=i+1                       # update i so that 'while' will terminate
    return (minsq, maxsq)
```

---

If I create this function `sqApprox(4)` and call it on IDE, I get output `(2, 0)`.

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: to format code start with a blank line then add four spaces to the beginning of each line of code then leave a blank line at the end

Comment: Why not forget about `minsq` and `maxsq` and just return `(i-1,i)` or `(i-1,i-1)` (depending on whether or not it is a perfect square)? All you need to do is find the last `i` with `i*i <= num` and you can do that with a 1-line while loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is why your code does what it does:

After the line `maxsq = minsq` is executed, both of those values are 1.

When we come to the loop

```
while i*i<=num:                     # set 'while' termination condition
    if i*i<=num and i >=minsq:  # complete inequality condition  
        minsq = i
    if i*i<=num and i <=maxsq:  # complete inequality condition
        maxsq = i
    i=i+1                       # update i so that 'while' will terminate
```

first note that inside the loop `i*i<=num`, so there is no need to retest it. Thus it is equivalent to:

```
 while i*i<=num: 
     if i >=minsq:  
         minsq = i
     if i <=maxsq:
         maxsq = i
     i=i+1
```

In the first pass through the loop `i == 0` but `maxsq == 1`, making the second condition true, hence setting `maxsq` equal to the current value of `i`, which is 0. In subsequent passes through the loop, `i <= maxsq` is false (since `maxsq == 0` but `i > 0`) hence `maxsq` is never moved beyond 0. On the other hand, the first condition in the while loop keeps updating `minsq` as intended.

I would recommend forgetting about both `minsq` and `maxsq` completely. Have the loop simply be:

```
while i*i <= num:
    i += 1 #shortcut for i = i + 1
```

When the loop is done executing, a simple test involving `i-1` is enough to determine what to return.

Comment: Thanks that helped.